# Prebuilt Java Servlet for MySQL database entry?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, open-source

I am looking for a good starting point for a servlet that is able to take in either POST or GET requests and decipher them into an action. This action would be a request to enter data into a table on a MySQL Database.

I've dealt with my own custom made servlets in eclipse before, but I want a prebuilt servlet which its only purpose is data entry for MySQL.

Does anyone know of a library or open source project that allows me to call simple routines for handling incoming requests like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a lot of web frameworks around,  from my personal preference I would recommend spring for dependency injection paired with struts-2